# Multiple date picker for cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, phonegap-plugins, jquery-multidatespicker

I am completely new for Cordova & PhoneGap and have been searching around for MultiDatePicker plugin for Cordova.

I see below plugin but its not multi date picker.
https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker

Below link lists all the phonegap plugins in which i don't see multidatepicker.
http://phonegap-plugins.com/

Any idea how to get this plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As Of My Knowledge there is no Plugin for multipledatepicker in cordova. If you are using jQuery in your Project Probably You can use **MultiDatesPicker for JqueryUi**.

Example code

```
var today = new Date();
var y = today.getFullYear();
$('#full-year').multiDatesPicker({
    addDates: ['10/14/'+y, '02/19/'+y, '01/14/'+y, '11/16/'+y],
    numberOfMonths: [3,4],
    defaultDate: '1/1/'+y
});
```

Reference Link [here](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But i am developing ionic app with cardova not jquery. I have seen multiple multidatepickers for ionic and while importing this in cardova it thorws an error and asks for plugin.xml. Any idea how to make ionic plugins for cardova?